# How to find all groups of a given order with trivial center in GAP?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

How can I find all groups of a given order with trivial center in GAP?

Comment: A group of order $64$ cannot have a trivial center, the center has at least two elements. In general, a $p$-group (a group with order $p^k$, where p is a prime and $k\ge 1$) has a center of size $p^l$, where $1\le l\le k$. Note, that the size of the center cannot be $p^{k-1}$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I edit my question now. I want a general command to find. I think command "Filtered" maybe is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GAP Most efficient way to check multiple properties of a group in the small group library](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553988/gap-most-efficient-way-to-check-multiple-properties-of-a-group-in-the-small-grou)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is Center(Size(G))=$1$. $G$ has a trivial center if and only if GAP returns true.

For example : order $36$

```
gap> n:=36;for j in [1..NrSmallGroups(n)] do G:=SmallGroup(n,j); if Size(Center(G))=1 then Print(IdGroup(G),"   ",StructureDescription(G),"\n");fi;od;
36
[ 36, 9 ]   (C3 x C3) : C4
[ 36, 10 ]   S3 x S3
gap>
```

Another possibility would be :

```
gap> n:=36;x:=PositionsProperty(List(AllSmallGroups(n)),G->Size(Center(G))=1);List(x,s->StructureDescription(SmallGroup(n,s)));
36
[ 9, 10 ]
[ "(C3 x C3) : C4", "S3 x S3" ]
gap>
```

The Filtered-command allows an even shorter way :

```
gap> n:=36;List(Filtered(AllSmallGroups(n),G->Size(Center(G))=1),StructureDescription);
36
[ "(C3 x C3) : C4", "S3 x S3" ]
gap>
```

Comment: `Filtered(AllSmallGroups(n),G->Size(Center(G))=1)` creates a big overhead since you have to generarate the full list `AllSmallGroups(n)` first. Better to use `AllSmallGroups(Size,n,g->Size(Center(g)),1);`